# Beautiful Soup and requests problem it doesn't show any text output

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am using beautiful soup and requests to print full text of the article of this wedsite

https://www.vanityfair.com/style/society/2014/06/monica-lewinsky-humiliation-culture

This is my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = requests.get("https://www.vanityfair.com/style/society/2014/06/monica-lewinsky-humiliation-culture")
html = url.text
page = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
match = page.find_all('div', 'parbase cn_text')
page_list = [[k.get_text() for k in i.find_all('p')] for i in match]

for i in page_list[:-2]:
   for k in i:
     print(k + '\n')
```

My code run without any error but it does't show any text in output plz help me find my error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### What happens?

You try to `find_all()` div tags with two classes that do not exists, so `match` is empty.

### How to fix that?

Use the correct pattern, I took the css selectors to avoid an additional loop:

```
select('article.article.main-content p')
```

List comprehension then looks like:

```
[p.get_text() for p in page.select('article.article.main-content p')]
```

**Working example**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = requests.get("https://www.vanityfair.com/style/society/2014/06/monica-lewinsky-humiliation-culture")
html = url.text
page = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')


print(*[p.get_text() for p in page.select('article.article.main-content p')], sep='\n')
```

Comment: ty for the explantion and the code works ty

Answer (score 0):

To get the article data select `div` that has a class `article__chunks`. Article data belonging to it.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = requests.get("https://www.vanityfair.com/style/society/2014/06/monica-lewinsky-humiliation-culture")
html = url.text
page = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
match = page.find('div', {'class': 'article__chunks'})

page_list = [[k.get_text() for k in i.find_all('p')] for i in match]

for i in page_list[:-2]:
   for k in i:
     print(k + '\n')
```